# The solution of $xy' = \sqrt{x^2 - y^2} + y$ according the answer key is $\arcsin y/x = \ln Cx$ sgn $x$ and $y = \pm x$. Why is there a sgn $x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The solution of $xy' = \sqrt{x^2 - y^2} + y$ according the answer key is $\arcsin y/x = \ln Cx\cdot \operatorname{sgn}x$ and $y = \pm x$. Why is there a $\operatorname{sgn} x$? So this is solved first by rearranging to $y' = \sqrt {1 - \dfrac {y^2}{x^2}} + \dfrac{y}{x}$ and then substituting using $u = y/x$ which will turn the equation into $\dfrac{dx}{x} = \dfrac{du}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}$ and here the only remaining task is to integrate both sides. Right side's integral is $\arcsin y/x + C$. Left side's is $\ln {|x|} + C = \ln {C|x|}$. Now the thing is that, as $C$ is arbitrary, then we can just write $\ln {Cx}$ right? Why is there even a $\operatorname{sgn} x$ in the solution? (I know that $|x| = x\operatorname{sgn} x$ but still I don't understand where is the necessity to write in that form).

Comment: $\ln|x|+C=\ln(|x|e^C) \neq \ln C|x|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first step, the root only absorbs $|x|$, the sign of $x$ remains outside,
$$
y'=s·\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{x^2}}+\frac{y}{x}
$$
Which means that you get a qualitatively different solution for $x<0$ than for $x>0$. The solution on both branches can have a different constant $C$.

---

Or try to avoid that substitution and set directly $y=x\sin(u(x))$. Then
$$
xy'=y+x^2\cos(u(x))u'(x)=|x\cos(u(x))|+y
$$
so that
$$
{\rm sgn}(\cos(u(x)))·u'(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}
$$
This shows that there are further sign cases to discuss.